# Kubernetes - Monitoring pod IO

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, provisioned-iops

I would like to monitor the IO which my pod is doing. Using commands like 'kubectl top pods/nodes', i can monitor CPU & Memory. But I am not sure how to monitor IO which my pod is doing, especially disk IO.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: you can query kubelet stats using the REST apis refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403810/how-to-get-pod-cpu-and-memory-usage-from-metrics-server

Comment: you can install helm chart for prometheus and grafana, it will give you required metrics

Answer (score 1):

Since you already used `kubectl top` command I assume you have metrics server. In order to have more advanced monitoring solution I would suggest to use `cAdvisor`,  `Prometheus` or `Elasticsearch`.

For getting started with Prometheus you can check [this article](https://www.replex.io/blog/kubernetes-in-production-the-ultimate-guide-to-monitoring-resource-metrics).

Elastic search has [System diskio](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-metricset-system-diskio.html)  and [Docker diskio](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-metricset-docker-diskio.html)  metrics set.  You can easily deploy it using [helm chart](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/master/elasticsearch).

[Part 3](https://blog.freshtracks.io/a-deep-dive-into-kubernetes-metrics-part-3-container-resource-metrics-361c5ee46e66) of the series about kubernetes monitoring is  especially focused on monitoring container metrics using cAdvisor.  Allthough it is worth checking whole series.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Most of them talk about CPU & Memory resource but not IO .. why ?

Comment: With cAdvisor you could monitor the disk as showed in the link above. Have you tried? Or need another metric that is no exposed by cAdvisor?